# Managed extensibility with System.AddIn

Tags: c#, system.addin

I am using System.AddIn to add new component to my application. Application successfully pick the newly added add in.

Currently if I want to add new addin then I need to create new project of class library type and then I need to code for that addin.

is it possible to add multiple addin to same class library so every time I need not to add new project?

If possible then how I find appropriate token at the time of loading the add in.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: two add-ins in one library? This is strange. What is the problem with adding new project? and by the way do you know about vsix feature in VS2010?

Comment: I am using VS2008. I didn't heard of that project. Actually i have used this concept with Scheduler. so now we are planning to add various kind of jobs which will be picked up by scheduler. Jobs will be treated as Add in. so many of them are small so keeping them in one class library is good for me.

Comment: I'd rather consider keeping them as one add-in but I might not understand what the job means in your case

Comment: i need to create one add in for one job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible to have multiple add-ins in one assembly.  Every class that is marked with  `[System.AddIn.AddInAttribute]` and extends the contract that you specify when doing a `FindAddIns` will resolve to a separate `AddInToken`.

In order to filter the set of tokens that are discovered, have a look at `System.AddIn.Pipeline.QualificationDataAttribute`.  This attribute lets you add name/value metadata to your add-in types that you can then access from `AddInToken`.